# Unable to understand Partition over query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    /* Formatted on 2014/07/15 11:08 (Formatter Plus v4.8.5) */
       SELECT   si_dda_platform.platform, si_dda_rel_contr.ctolocpr,
       si_dda_prod.codprod, si_dda_prod.nomprod2,
       AVG (AVG (rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.imporip))  
       OVER (PARTITION BY rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idgruemp, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.fecdata, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codcont, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idempr, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcent, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codprod, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcontr, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idscontr)
     / SUM (1) OVER (PARTITION BY rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idgruemp,  -- sum over partition
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.fecdata, 
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codcont, 
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idempr, 
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcent, 
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codprod, 
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcontr, 
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idscontr),
       AVG (AVG (rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.imporico)) OVER ,  -- Avg over partition
       (PARTITION BY rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idgruemp, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.fecdata, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codcont, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idempr, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcent, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codprod, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcontr, 
       rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idscontr)
     / SUM (1) OVER (PARTITION BY rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idgruemp, -- Sum over partition    
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.fecdata, 
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codcont, 
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idempr, 
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcent, 
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codprod, 
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcontr, 
      rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idscontr),
     SUM (rpt_ft_dd_plbal.isafccdp)
   FROM si_dda_rel_contr,
     rpt_ft_dc_contr rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d,
     si_dda_prod,
     si_dda_scen,
     si_ddj_crit,
     si_dda_platform,
     rpt_ft_dd_plbal,
     rpt_cnf_fechas_d,
     rpt_cnf_period_d
     WHERE (    rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idempr = si_dda_prod.idempr
       AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codprod = si_dda_prod.codprod
     )
     AND (    rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idempr = si_ddj_crit.idempr
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codcrite = si_ddj_crit.codjen6
     )
    AND (    rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idempr = si_dda_scen.idempr
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idescena = si_dda_scen.idescena
     )
     AND (rpt_cnf_fechas_d.fecdata = rpt_ft_dd_plbal.fecdata)
     AND (rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idgruemp = '0022')
     AND (rpt_ft_dd_plbal.acumtemp = rpt_cnf_period_d.acumtemp)
      AND (    rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idgruemp = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idgruemp(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.fecdata = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.fecdata(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codcont = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codcont(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idempr = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idempr(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idcent = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcent(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codprod = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codprod(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idcontr = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcontr(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idscontr = rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idscontr(+)
     )
      AND (    rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idempr = si_dda_rel_contr.idempr(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idcent = si_dda_rel_contr.idcent(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codprod = si_dda_rel_contr.idprod(+)
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idcontr = si_dda_rel_contr.idcontr(+)
     )
      AND (    rpt_ft_dd_plbal.idempr = si_dda_platform.idempr
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codprod = si_dda_platform.codprod
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.codsprod = si_dda_platform.codsprod
      AND rpt_ft_dd_plbal.coestref = si_dda_platform.coestref
     )
      AND (    to_char(rpt_cnf_fechas_d.fecdata,'YYYYMMDD') ='20140228'
      AND ((rpt_cnf_period_d.acumtemp) = 'DAY')
      AND ((si_dda_scen.idescena) = '01')
      AND ((si_ddj_crit.codjen3) = '30010')
     )
       AND si_dda_platform.platform = 'ALFA'
    GROUP BY 1,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idgruemp,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.fecdata,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codcont,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idempr,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcent,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.codprod,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idcontr,
     rpt_ft_dc_con_c_d.idscontr,
     si_dda_platform.platform,
     si_dda_rel_contr.ctolocpr,
     si_dda_prod.codprod,
     si_dda_prod.nomprod2
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions011.htm see analytic example at the bottom

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you please xplain Why there are two avg functions used and what is the meaning of three partition over functions used in the query? Could you please explain in simple the result of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the query in an abstract way. (I just glanced at the WHERE clause.)

```
SELECT   
    <column_list>
    AVG (<expression>) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>) / SUM (1) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>),
    AVG (<expression>) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>) / SUM (1) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>),
    SUM (<column_name>)
FROM <many tables>
WHERE <where conditions, join conditions, outer join expressions, . . .>
GROUP BY <column_list>
```

This kind of construction

```
AVG (<expression>) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>)
```

calculates an average over a subset of rows. The subset is determined by the column_list in the partition.

So *this* kind of construction

```
AVG (<expression>) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>) / SUM (1) OVER (PARTITION BY <column_list>),
```

is effectively dividing the average by the number of rows in the same partition. (That strikes me as a little odd, and worth investigating if I were in your shoes.) It's the same partition, because the column_list in the first `partition by` is identical to the column_list in the second `partition by`. In fact, all four of the partitions are identical.

There are two of those `AVG() OVER (PARTITION BY...)` constructions. One is concerned with the average of "imporip"; the other is concerned with the average of "imporico".

I'll leave it to an Oracle expert to explain the old outer join syntax if you need that.